# How to allow to jump only once in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey Guys im Currently working on an 2D Endlessrunner and i need help, i want to only jump once until the character touches the ground again could anyone help me please i would be very thankfull
heres the code for the character :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dino : MonoBehaviour
{

    bool isJumping;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        isJumping = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("space"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 20, 0);
            isJumping = true;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the is jumping condition to your jump code like this:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("space") && !isJumping)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 20, 0);
        isJumping = true;
    } 
}
```

And handle the `isJumping`  boolean in the collision logic of your character with the ground. You can keep a reference to the floor collider to check if whats dino is colliding with is the floor:

```
public collider2D floorCol; //attach in unity editor
OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    //check you are colliding with the floor
    if (collision.collider == floorCol)
        isJumping = false;
}
```

assuming 2d for simplicity's sake.

Comment: thank u so much its actually my first time discovering unity and c# haha

Comment: cool, good luck :)